# Getting previous return value with new value concatenated using recursion

Tags: java, recursion

I'm working a problem on recursion. After writing the code requested, the site I'm working from runs the code with different values as input.  However, the first run works properly, but all subsequent runs concatenate the return value of the first run with the values of each of the subsequent runs.

I am also getting a stack overflow error at the end.

I need help!

Here is the code:

```
package com.company;

import static java.lang.System.*;

public class Main {

    public static String returnValue="";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        repeat("this is fun", 1);
        out.println(returnValue);
    }
    public static String repeat(String s, int i){
        if (i==0) {
            return returnValue;
        }
        else{
            returnValue+=s;
            repeat(s,i-1);
        }
        return returnValue;
    }
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try putting `returnValue="";` inside your `main()`.

Comment: When I run the code it just prints 'this is fun'. Which is exactly what your code does.
' What do you expect as a result btw?

Comment: hint: `static`..

Comment: you should get stackoverflow error only if recursion break condition fails. What int value param are you passing here `repeat("this is fun", 1);` ? if it is `<0` then it will fail. Also if you are passing a high value so that it's size exceeds String length limit then also it will fail.

Answer (score 1):

You need to move the `static returnValue` into the method. You then need to control the result by capturing the string returned by the inner recursive call.

Something like:

```
public static String repeat(String s, int i){
    String returnValue="";
    if (i==0) {
        return returnValue;
    }
    else{
        returnValue+=s + repeat(s,i-1);
    }
    return returnValue;
}
```

NB: This may not be the equivalent algorithm to what you intend but it should demonstrate the technique.

If that is the correct solution then you can tidy up with:

```
public static String repeat(String s, int i){
    if (i==0) {
        return "";
    } else {
        return s + repeat(s,i-1);
    }
}
```

Comment: That did it! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are comfortable with expressions:

```
public static String repeat(String s, int i) {
  return i <= 0
         ? ""
         : s + repeat(s, i - 1);
}
```

and you can get rid of the static attribute!